# ngFor create 2 rows

Tags: html, angular

Using [Angular 2 ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) I'm creating a table.

My problem is that `my data array` contains `elements` such that each element should create 2 **consecutive** rows in the table (Using different fields, The second row is collapsible with more data)

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let element of data; let i = index">
       <th>...<th>
       ...
       <td>...<td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Problem is that `tbody` doesn't allow any attribute beside `<tr>`.

**I'm looking for something like**

```
<tbody>
   <template *ngFor="let element of data; let i = index">
       <tr>...</tr> //row 1
       <tr>...</tr> //row 2
   </template>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

That exists with slightly different syntax:

```
<template ngFor let-element [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
   <tr>...</tr> //row 1
   <tr>...</tr> //row 2
</template>
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of data let i=index">
   <tr>...</tr> //row 1
   <tr>...</tr> //row 2
</ng-container>
```

update for >= 4.0.0 `<template>` was changed to `<ng-template>`

```
<ng-template ngFor let-element [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
   <tr>...</tr> //row 1
   <tr>...</tr> //row 2
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't understand why the syntax difference. I did see ithis syntax in the documentation and tried it with *ngFor which didn't work (typo). Also my IDE complains that this syntax is "not allowed" here and no autocomplete.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template I don't know about the IDE. What I showed in my answer is the canonical syntax. `*ngFor` is syntactic sugar.

Comment: I had a need for this a few days ago but I implemented it via bootstrap 3 row and col-xx-y classes. The second row was activated by the first one and it would act as a drill-down table. Basically I tried to avoid "disintegrating" *ngFor into various approaches throughout the project and wanted to keep it uniform across every view.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic can you please share some code? More so if it's relevant to bootstrap 4.

Comment: Super helpful! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I faced it the same problem and i didn't find any good solution. But after a deep reseach i found this ng-container and it worked very well. U can see it in action bellow

https://plnkr.co/edit/F8ohXKLHvvbHXAqGESQN?p=preview

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of posts">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button (click)="openCloseRow(obj.id)">
                    <span *ngIf="rowSelected!=obj.id; else close">Open</span>
                      <ng-template #close>
                        <span>Close</span>
                        </ng-template>
                </button>
            </td> 
          <td>{{obj.date}}</td>
          <td>
              {{obj.subject}}
          </td>
          <td>{{obj.numComents}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="rowSelected==obj.id">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                                   
                            <th style="width:15%;">Comment</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let q of obj.comments">                                  
                            <td style="width:15%;">{{q}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: ng-container will add element inside table body which is not allowed in html.. demo not working.

Comment: The plunker may not work but using ng-container works perfrecty.   There are no artifacts in the table.