# Bootstrap table with nested components in angular2

Tags: angular2-template

I'm the begginer with angular2, and i try to build bootstrap table with nested components, the child component is display in single cell. Probably I'm doing something wrong with ngFor loop. This is my child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../customer';
import { CustomersComponent } from '../customers.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'single-customer',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  inputs:['customer'],
  templateUrl: './single-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-customer.component.css']
})
export class SingleCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    customer: Customer;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and template:

```
<td>
        {{customer.surname | uppercase}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{customer.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{customer.phone}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{customer.mail}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{customer.comments}}
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".update-customer-modal" ng-click="setCustomerData(customer)">Edytuj</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete-customer-modal" ng-click="setCustomerData(customer)">Usuń</button></td>
<!-- </tr> -->
```

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { SingleCustomerComponent } from './single-customer/single-customer.component';
import { Customer } from './customer';
import { CustomersService } from './customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css'],
  providers: [CustomersService], 
})

export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

    customers: Customer[];
    customersLength: number;

    constructor(private _customersService: CustomersService) {
     }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCustomers();
    }

    getCustomers(){
        this._customersService.getCustomers().then((res) => {
            this.customers = res;
            this.customersLength = this.customers.length;
    });
}
}
```

parent template:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>NAZWISKO</td>
                            <td>IMIĘ</td>
                            <td>TELEFON</td>
                            <td>MAIL</td>
                            <td>URODZINY</td>
                            <td>UWAGI</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
                       <single-customer [customer]="customer"></single-customer>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and parents module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers.component';
import { SingleCustomerComponent } from './single-customer/single-customer.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [CustomersComponent, SingleCustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, what error you are getting please specify that

Comment: when I put the component as a table row it's not display as a row, but each instant of component is in one cell and the table has one column

Comment: Not getting it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Table element in HTML just allows `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` and `tr` as children.

You can change your children component's selector to:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[single-customer]',
    ...
})
export class SingleCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
```

And change your parent template to:

```
...    
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers"
        single-customer
        [customer]="customer">
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar. Except, I need two tr elements for each customer. So I can't attach the ngFor to the <tr> because it shows only one <tr> and I can't wrap two <tr>s in a component because then I get the extra tag around the <tr>s which breaks the table.

Comment: Did you try to wrap your two `<tr>` inside a `<ng-container>`? It doesn't create a wrapper element

Comment: This other post actually gave me the exact answer I needed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097560/1174250